# keeping changed data global variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, global-variables

I have a global variable that I change in a function but when I call the global variable later in code in a different function, it doesn't store the change when the variable is first called:

```
    name = "noname"

    def username():
        print ("It would help if I had a name to go by, please enter a   name.")
        global name
        name = input()

     def character():
        global name
        print ("Character overview:\nName:"+name+"")
```

And the output of character() is noname instead of the input.
Is there a way keeping the change in the first function?

Comment: Can you include more information on how you are calling this? Using the above and then simply calling `username()` and then `character()`, it works fine. There must be something else interfering that is not shown here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
name = "noname"

def user():
    global name
    name = input()

def char():
    # Works with or without global here
    print(name)

user()
char()
```